# How to combine min- and max-width with a wrapper?

Tags: html, css

I've managed to center my 2-column layout with a wrapper.
I'd like to make it somehow responsive as well, so I thought about using min- and max-width values. But as soon as I insert them, the layout breaks and isn't centered anymore.

Any advice? Or should I look for a totally different approach?

Here's the basic HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sidebarfix">
            <nav>
                <li><a class="navlink"; href="">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="navlink"; href="">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="navlink"; href="">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a class="navlink"; href="">Link 4</a></li>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #EFEFEF;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
width: 600px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 300px;
float: left;
position: relative;
padding: 0 2.5em 0 2.5em;
margin: 0;
}

#sidebar {
width: 200px;
float: right;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

#sidebarfix {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Go here for the complete JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/timothys_monster/0db4sL6d/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i would suggest to use bootstrap, its grate framework and save a lot of time. But if you want to write it by yourself its strongly depends what kind of layout you want to make. If you want to make standard boxed layout you could simple give fixed width to body

Like

```
body {width: 860px; background-color: black; margin: 0px auto;}
html {background-color: white;}
```

Then you can play with % width and also you could use `@media screen` . But the best way would be simple add Bootstrap.

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
[Media rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Oh thank you very much! I will definitely have a look at Bootstrap. But I'd like to do it from scratch as well. Will play around with a fixed width to body. Thanks for the hint.